# modal bottom sheet after context pop

Tags: flutter

This `ListTile` is in modal bottom sheet inside a build method.
It dismisses the current bottom sheet first.
Then it's showing a modal bottom sheet when tapped on.

It actually works.

But my confusion is shouldn't it produce an error about the context that has been popped already??.

```
    ListTile(
      title: Text('Test'),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();  // Dismiss current bottom sheet
        showModalBottomSheet(  // Show new bottom sheet
          context: context,  // Using the same popped context?
          builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              child: Text('test test'),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This `context` belongs to the `build(BuildContext context)` method of your wrapping widget. As the widget stays in place, the context is valid.

If you are interested in how it works: When you call `Navigator.of(context)`, it walks up the tree to find the nearest `Navigator` widget, starting at this context. And when you show the new bottom sheet, it does the same. So any context will do as long as it is under the current `Navigator`.